# How to use Postgres / Prisma as a queue, preventing workers from selecting already selected rows

Tags: postgresql, queue, locking, prisma

I have a 'queue' table that is essentially just a big list of id's. I then have a worker process that runs, concurrently, every 2 seconds and takes 10 id's from the queue; processes the id's and then deletes the id's off the queue only if successful.

The problem arises when the seconds job starts before the first job has time to finish and takes id's off the queue that are already being processed.

I'm using Prisma so I'm not sure of the underlying SQL in Postgres but I'm doing all of my calls inside a transaction and setting the transaction isolation level to 'Serialized', which correctly fails due to a write conflict.

I've looked into 'ACCESS EXCLUSIVE' lock in Postgres but doesn't this lock the entire table rather than just the rows I select? Preventing other working from even accessing the table?

I've also looked into RabbitMQ as a solution but I need the queue to be selected in descending order and RabbitMQ priorities only has a priority level up to 255. Not only this but the queue has over a billion id's so I'd rather it not be stored in memory.

I'm more than open to look into any other solutions if anyone can think of any that fits my requirements.